# How to display data between two dates in php using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

How to display this from mysql..??

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tour_table WHERE visited_date BETWEEN '" . $date1_ob . "' AND '" . $date2_ob . "'");
```

Comment: what is wrong with your query?

Comment: inb4 don't use mysql use mysqli!

Comment: Are you storing date as date formate or seconds..??

Comment: What do you mean *display from mysql*?

Comment: For your query to work, `$date1_ob` must be a valide format e.g. `0000-00-00`

Comment: i have validate to that @ArtPlanteur

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array($sql)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use following  , i assume `$date1_ob` and `$date2_ob` are in correct format

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tour_table WHERE visited_date >='" . $date1_ob . "' AND visited_date <= '" . $date2_ob . "'");
```